# In Alpine.js the above code involving modal is not working and the below code not involving modal is working

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

```html
@{
    int MOOD = 167;
}
        
<div x-data="{ modalOpen: false ,productName : null }" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">
    <button @@click="modalOpen = true;fetchVariants()">Open Modal</button>

    <div x-show="modalOpen" class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
            <div x-text="productName"></div>

            <button @@click="modalOpen = false">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div x-data="{  variants: [] ,productName : null }" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">
    <button @@click="fetchVariants">Fetch Data</button>
    <!-- Trigger for Modal -->
    <div x-text="productName"></div>
    <template x-for="variant in variants">
        <li>
            <p>Price: <span x-text="variant.price"></span></p>
        </li>
    </template>
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify(variants)"></div>
</div>
    

<script>

    function fetchVariants() {
    
        const productId = document.querySelector('[x-bind\\:data-product-id]').getAttribute('data-product-id');
        const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((products) => {
                this.variants = products.variant;
                this.productName = products.productName;
                console.log(this.productName);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

what could be the reason for the above code not working? It is opening the modal.The first code is calling fetchVariants() and printing console.

The second code works.

Answer (score 0):

The *fetchVariants()* function has a different context than your Alpine object so basically it can't  acess to the *Alpine object* properties and that's why the data of the modal code is not updated.
However, in the other sample code you are not calling directly the function in the *onClick* event, you are passing a different thing: omitting the brackets after the function name, the *Alpine object* doesn't receives the function's result but it receives a reference to the function. Unexpectedly (for me) the function is also executed inside the *Alpine object* so it can access to it's scope. I don't know if this is a *bug* or a *feature*, however it's the first time I've seen this situation because it's usually done differently.

Basically you should include your function (or another function that calls it and gets the results) in the *x-data* object:

```html
<div x-data="xdata()" x-bind:data-product-id="@MOOD">

    <button @@click="modalOpen = true; fetchVariants()">Open Modal</button>

    <div x-show="modalOpen" class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
    
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
        
            <div x-text="productName"></div>
            
            <button @@click="modalOpen = false">Close</button>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>

<script>

    function xdata ()  {

        return {
        
            modalOpen: false,
            productName: null,

            fetchVariants: function () {

                const productId = document.querySelector("[x-bind\\:data-product-id]").getAttribute("data-product-id");
                const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

                fetch(url)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then((products) => {

                        this.productName = products.productName;
                        console.log(this.productName);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

The upper code works from Alpine V2.

With Alpine V3 a better approach is recommended: ([see here](https://alpinejs.dev/upgrade-guide#alpine-data-instead-of-global-functions))

```html
<div x-data="myComponent" data-product-id="@MOOD">  <!-- if MOOD is a constant from the backend, you can remove x-bind -->

    <button @@click="modalOpen = true; fetchVariants()">Open Modal</button>

    <div x-show="modalOpen" class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
    
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
        
            <div x-text="productName"></div>

            <button @@click="modalOpen = false">Close</button>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>

<script>

    document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {

        Alpine.data("myComponent", () => ({

            modalOpen: false,
            productName: null,

            fetchVariants: function () {

                const productId = document.querySelector("[data-product-id]").dataset.productId;
                const url = `/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${productId}`;

                 fetch(url)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then((products) => {

                        this.productName = products.productName;
                        console.log(this.productName);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            }
        }));
    });

</script>
```